# QTableView memory leak

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview, pyqt6

I have a QMainWindow object containing a button. It opens another QMainWindow containing a QTableView. When I close the mainwindow containing the table, most of the memory is released but not all of it. There seems like something is causing memory leak. I have tried destroying the objects, create close events which set the table to None, clear the table data etc. but nothing worked.

I am on windows and am just tracking memory usage with task manager. If i close and open the table window multiple times, the memory usage keeps increasing.

**Memory usage:**
Upon app start: 10.9 MB
After opening mainwindow containing table: 256.8 MB
After closing mainwindow containing table: 82.4 MB

What contains the 71.5 MB difference?

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QTableView, QMainWindow
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal
from PyQt6.QtGui import QAction, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt6 App")
        self.resize(200, 100)

        # Button
        self.button = QPushButton("Open Table")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.open_table)

        # Layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        widget = QWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def open_table(self):
        # Open the table window 
        self.table_window = TableMainWindow()    
        self.table_window.show()                 
        self.table_window.winClosed.connect(self.cleanup)
        
    def cleanup(self):  
        self.table_window.table.clear_table()  # does not seem to do anything
        self.table_window.table.deleteLater()  # does not seem to do anything
        self.table_window.deleteLater()

class TableMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    winClosed = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = Table()
        self.setup_ui()

    def closeEvent(self, event):

        self.winClosed.emit(self)
        event.accept()

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.setGeometry(400, 50, 600, 500)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)


class Table(QTableView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"]
        data = [{col: "Sample Cell Text" for col in self.columns} for i in range(100000)]
        
        self.build_table()
        self.load_data(data)
        
    def build_table(self):
        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.setColumnCount(len(self.columns))
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.columns)

    def load_data(self, data):
        for row in range(0, len(data)):
            self.insert_row(row, data[row])
            
    def insert_row(self, row, data):
        items = []
        for index, column in enumerate(self.columns):
            items.append(QStandardItem(str(data[column])))
        self.model.insertRow(row, items)

    def clear_table(self):
        self.model.removeRows(0, self.model.rowCount())         


       
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tried destroying the objects, create close events which set the table to None, clear the table data etc. but nothing worked. I was expecting for the memory to return to the level before I open the table mainwindow.

Comment: There are many parts in play here. First of all, Python doesn't normally completely release allocated memory, even after "deleting" objects. Then OS implementation may play some role, meaning that, depending on how you're actually monitoring memory usage, you may be actually seeing "ghosts" of a process usage (note that I'm oversimplifying *a lot*, things are actually quite more complex) depending on how the memory monitor accesses system memory usage. Then, you have to consider that PyQt (as PySide) is a *binding*, and memory management, just like object lifespan, is quite tricky.

Comment: For instance, a Qt object may be alive and well even after all its python references have been destroyed. Similarly, even after `deleteLater()` has been called on a QObject, its python counterpart may still exist. When dealing with complex object structures, things may become quite tricky, and, at some level, you reach a point where there's almost no certain way to know how objects are actually still "alive", unless you're extremely careful about their creation/destruction. In any case, Python doesn't normally *waste* memory: try to create again the table and its model and see what happens.

Comment: @musicamante I am on windows and am just tracking memory usage with task manager. If i close and open the table window multiple times, the memory usage keeps increasing. I edited my question to reflect this information. Because the memory usage keeps increasing as I close and open the window multiple times, it makes me think there is a memory leak somewhere.